# Online edition upgrade Windows Server 2012 (R2)

Tags: windows-server-2012, window, windows-server, dism, windows-edition

I had to find a way to upgrade a server from Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard to Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition. A colleague did the installation of the Standard edition instead of the required Datacenter...

So the question was : how to convert a Windows Server Edition from Standard to Datacenter, without having to manipulate offline ?

Comment: Check the current edition `DISM /online /Get-CurrentEdition`, check if it's upgradeable `DISM /online /Get-TargetEditions`, and if it is `DISM /online /Set-Edition:<edition ID> /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula`. Two restarts latter you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches, I found the solution to my answer. I had to use the DISM command, with this syntax :

```
dism /online /Set-Edition:ServerDatacenter /productKey:<valid datacenter PK> /AcceptEula
```

After a reboot, my server was finally a Datacenter Edition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you (not) read the comment of Brian?

Comment: In fact, I already knew the answer, I tried to share a knowledge, but misread the Self-Answer topic. So the post was locked, and before I could validate my own answer, it appears that Brian wrote a comment. Btw, thanks for the help.